# Use of "but" by Jack London

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, word-usage

The subordinate clause "From the way..." I understand the meaning of, however the main clause's meaning I do not. Would, if rephrased as, "I wouldn't wonder this time but what he [would die from]", be meaningfully equivalent to the below quote?

> ["From the way he cut up the other time you went away, I wouldn't wonder this time but what he died"](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/White_Fang/21)

Comment: Could it be that last time he got sick, and this time maybe died? I wouldn't wonder *that maybe* (but what) ...

Comment: Sorry I should have explained the context of the situation. The sentence is from White Fang by Jack London. [he] refers to a dog (White Fang) and the person who states the quote is a farm hand or the equivalent for someone who works on a ranch who is commenting on White Fang's devotion to being in close proximity to his master and doing anything to achieve this.  I don't know if this would help however

Comment: It's an archaic way of saying "except that".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "From the way he cut up the other time you went away, I wouldn't wonder this time but what he died."

This is almost incomprehensible to a speaker of Modern English, who would probably guess it meant *"I wouldn't be surprised if he died."*

However, this is not quite accurate and it is best to understand **but what** and **but that** as an idiom in which the **that/what** can be ignored:

The OED

> 9. After various verbs in negative or interrogative constructions, reversing the effect of the negative or interrogative so as to affirm more emphatically the dependent clause (e.g. I don't know but she's got notions into her head = ‘I think it likely that she's got notions into her head’). **Frequently in but that.**

Thus

"From the way he cut up the other time you went away, I think it is likely that he will die.”